# Probability of 'elementary subtraction'

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

The decimal parts of two irrational numbers in $(0,1)$ taken at random are found to $2014$ places. The probability that the smaller one can be subtracted from the other without **borrowing** can be expressed as $p^k$, where $p$ is a rational number and $k>1000$ is a positive integer. Find the last three digits of $\lfloor{100(p+k+1)}\rfloor$

Assume for this question that the digit in first decimal place of the larger number is greater than the digit in that of the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the assumption about the leading digits, we may cobsider all other digits as indpendant uniform radndom variables $\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$
No borrowing occurs iff all digits of the first are $\ge$ the corresponding digits of the second.
For a single place the probability of this is $\frac{10+9+8+\ldots +1}{100}=\frac{11}{20}$. Thus the total probability is $\left(\frac {11}{20}\right)^{2013}$ (again note that the first digit is to be ignored).